# Single specific character removal without slicing nor strip ,

Tags: python, string

how can i remove a single character from a string ?
Basically i have a string like :
 `abccbaa`

I wish to remove the first and last letter.  With the `string.rstrip` or `string.lstrip` methods all of the occurrences are removed and i get a string `bccb`. the same goes to `replace`.
is there a way of doing so ? i cannot import anything , i cant use slicing (except accessing single letter ) . Also I cannot use any kind of loops as well .

To get the whole picture , i need to write a recursive palindrome algorithm. My current code is:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if s == '':
        return True
    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False
    else:
        s = s.replace(s[0], '')
        s = s.replace(s[-1], '')
        return is_palindrome(s)


print is_palindrome("abccbaa")
```

as you can see it will work unless provides with a string like the one in the print line , since more than "edge" letters are stripped .

Comment: i can input my code , but it is irrelevant to the question . yes it is indeed my homework , i need to write a recursive palindrome . BUT since i dont ask other to solve my homework , Im asking a specific question under specific circumstances in which ive encountered a problem . Also as ive written before , slicing is irrelevant .

Comment: `replace("a","",1)` solves the first removal. And no, your code isn't irrelevant. It shows what you've tried, so we can try to improve it, and we get an idea of what you want.

Comment: so you can use recursion?

Comment: yes i just cant use loops , imported methods and slicing aswell since the mission is to write it recursively

Comment: You could do it by converting to list and using `pop()`. However, a better solution might be to add two more parameters to your function for left index and right index and compare those values.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing/replacing the string isn't needed and is costly because it creates strings over and over. In languages where strings are much less convenient to handle (like C), you wouldn't even have imagined to do like that.

Of course you need some kind of looping, but recursion takes care of that.

You could do it "the old way" just pass the start & end indices recursively, with a nested function to hide the start condition to the caller:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    def internal_method(s,start,end):
        if start>=end:
            return True
        if s[start] != s[end]:
            return False
        else:
            return internal_method(s,start+1,end-1)
    return internal_method(s,0,len(s)-1)
```

recursion stops if `start` meets `end` or if checked letters don't match (with a different outcome of course)

testing a little bit seems to work :)

```
>>> is_palindrome("")
True
>>> is_palindrome("a")
True
>>> is_palindrome("ab")
False
>>> is_palindrome("aba")
True
>>> is_palindrome("abba")
True
>>> is_palindrome("abbc")
False
```

Comment: Thank you very much , great answer exactly what i was looking for . Is there any material you would recommend for me to develop this kind of thinking ?

Comment: Well, no, but trying to think about performance before using the bazooka to swat a fly helps. Python has a lot of built-ins but your teachers didn't want you to use them because it was underperformant to do so. Single letter slicing (in a loop or recursive) is the fastest approach.

Comment: also your question is symptomatic of XY problem (improved when you posted the code): you know how to slice/replace, so you want to use it for your problem, when it's not adapted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess at what you are looking for here since your question wasn't all that clear but this works for taking off the first and last character of the word you provided?

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Nov 12 2018, 12:56:03) 
>>> string = "abccbaa"
>>> print(string[1:-1])
bccba
```

Comment: slicing is not an option except for accessing single letter .